# Powerline bash prompt not colorized in tmux

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux, colors

The bash/zsh commandline prompt is not displaying colors in tmux, even though I managed to get the powerline itself working (with colors).

The prompt works fine in pure bash/zsh.

I am getting the proper output, only the colors are not displayed.

I have

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

in my `.tmux.conf`.

Additionally, I have

```
"term_truecolor": "true"
```

changing that to false did not make a difference.

I read through the documentation, and it seems that setting

```
 additional_escapes to "tmux" or "screen"
```

should help. With "tmux" I am getting colors, but also some undesired spaces and ] characters in the prompt.

I also tried setting "screen-256color" or running tmux with -2 option. Any ideas?